# Galleria and jQuery Error

Tags: jquery, lightbox, galleria, shadowbox

Can someone help me resolve an issue?

http://flipburgerboutique.com/photos/#lightbox-1

I'm seeing this error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'jQuery('.gallery').galleria({  extend: function(options) {  var
>   gallery = this;  }  })')

I'm not sure what this means and how to fix it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Change `jQuery('.gallery').galleria({` to `$('.gallery').galleria({` - there seems to be a jQuery library conflict somewhere.

Comment: This worked! I also had to update Galleria to version 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that there is no galleria function for the elements that have the class gallery.

Have a read through this http://galleria.io/docs/getting_started/beginners_guide/ and check the docs to see how to do what you want to do properly.

Maybe something like this

```
Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
Galleria.run('.gallery');
```

instead of

```
jQuery('.gallery').galleria({
    extend: function(options) {
        var gallery = this;
    }
});
```

You are using wordpress though so if this is a plugin I'm not sure you should be messing with its code. You have probably done something wrong with your shortcodes or something.

EDIT:

On a quick skim of the docs http://galleria.io/docs/references/extending/#using-the-extend-option it seems like what you want is this:

```
Galleria.run('.gallery', {

    extend: function(options) {
        var gallery = this;
    }
});
```

Comment: @oswebdesign ah that would explain why he was trying that function call in the first place. I've never touched Galleria so I didn't know.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I got it working using Archer's comment above.

Comment: @Rested Yeah, me neither. I saw him include a 1.2.4 version or something in the head and I figured it was outdated when I went to go look at the API docs.